# How to Find Select Option value

Tags: php

```php
<select name="size[]" id="min_size" class="optional selectpicker input-
price" data-live-search="true" required>
<option value="">Choose One</option>

<?php
foreach ($size_combo[$value] as $key => $row) {

  $output.='<option value="'.$row.'">'.$size[$row].'</option>';

}

$output.='</select>';
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Ramesh. Please make sure to read [How to ask a good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And come back to edit your question.

Comment: Hi! I have edited your code for code formatting. I changed the last line to `$output.='</select>';` and closed the PHP tag for you. You also have to echo `$output` afterwards at some point.

Answer (score 1):

You want to find the value in the foreach right?
Then use an `if()` statement to find which loop you want to get the value.

```
Choose One';
foreach ($size_combo[$value] as $key => $row) {

if($key == 'your_number') {
   <br>print_r($size_combo);
   <br>$output.=''.$size[$row].'';
}

}

$output.='enter code here
```

Comment: Hi! `dd()` is for Laravel. For pure PHP, `var_dump()` or `print_r()` should work better.

Comment: oh yea sorry about that